# AWS custom white-label nameservers are not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

1. I created reusable delegation set nameservers
2. Got their IPs and created entries at my domain DNS zone (Namecheap) as n1.example.com, ns2... pointing to the nameservers' IPs
3. Created glue records for the same at Namecheap
4. Now when I am trying to add these nameservers to other domains, it's not working

Can someone please help me with this?